# Magento + Varnish -> module double effect + show poll block even if disabled

Tags: magento, caching, memcached, varnish

I'm hosted on siteground and I have enbaled all the cache option (I'm using magento 1.9.1):

- Varnish Static Cache
- Varnish Dynamic Cache
- Memcached

Unfortunately the second one duplicate the effect of my [minicart module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/header-mini-cart.html), this is its xml:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">


<default>
  <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/hm/minicart.js</name><params/></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/hm/minicart.css</stylesheet></action>
  </reference>
  <reference name="header">
            <reference name="top.links">
                <remove name="checkout_cart_link"/>
                <block type="minicart/view" name="minicart_toplink" template="minicart/toplink.phtml" >
                    <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" as="topcart" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml"/>
                </block>
                <action method="addLinkBlock"><blockName>minicart_toplink</blockName></action>
                <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link_minicart">
                    <action method="addCheckoutLink"></action>
                </block>
            </reference>
        </reference>
  </default>
</layout>
```

and this is the error:
[image]
I have also tried to clean all the cache that I could, but with no success...
The other problem (that I don't know to which one of the cache is related to) doesn't allow me to remove the poll sidebar block, in particular the module is disable through the admin panel and actually I can't see anything related to poll managment, but the block is still displayed in the frontend, so I had to remove all the polls from my database to avoid to show the block.
Siteground said that this problem is related to my theme, but I don't know where to put my hands, since it's default theme with some xml and css edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are on Siteground as well with Magento 1.9.1

We do NOT use Varnish Dynamic cache since this creates many problems with our completely basic theme (few blocks changed). Same on previous Magento versions.

Tried tickets but it's due to our (standard) theme.... so no VDC for us either.

I suggest, just turn it to off.

Also, remember to log out of Magento and use a INCOGNITO browser (mode) to check your site, usually the header affected by VDC as well. Refresh the page even in the incognito browser to get a fresh one.

Comment: I have given up to, now I'm using memcached+page speed+lesti:FPC. When the sales volume will be big enough probably we will move to Nexcess that looks like more "open"